# Java Spring there is a way to extend @Scheduled to read a file

Tags: java, spring, annotations, scheduled-tasks

I have some tasks to do already after my application is initialized and after periodically, so I do that:

```
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000)  
  public void scheduleFixedRateTask() {
        System.out.println("Fixed rate task - " + System.currentTimeMillis()/10000);
  }
```

But some times I need to update the interval, and I dont want to stop my application every time to do this... So there is a way to extend @Scheduled to read some file with the interval? I'm using Spring

Comment: What library provides the `@Scheduled` annotation?

Comment: Sorry Its a Spring library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `fixedRate` and `fixedRateString` cannot be changed dynamically.

You will be better of using a [Trigger](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-trigger-interface)
available in the [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/UpdateTrigger) library with Spring to be able to modify the interval time.